# jquery shake not working when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("flashab").effect( "shake",
    {times:4}, 50 );
}};
```

that should make flashab shake onload. but it doesn't.
please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `$('flashab')` with `$('#flashab')` if the element has flashab for **id** or `$('.flashab')` if it has flashab for **class**

Comment: done that but it still doesn't work, but it does work with $( document ).click(function() {

Comment: @user2166538 A Fiddle would be useful in a situation like this

Comment: @user2166538 if the solution works for you, you should accept the answer, it will mark the question as resolved.